# Keras Custom CNN Model gives Fluctuating results while serving

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

I am running a custom CNN model in Keras,

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

nb_train_samples = 213
nb_validation_samples = 212
epochs = 200
batch_size = 32

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

When I serve the model, I am getting fluctuating results i.e. Each time I try predicting, for the same image it gives me different probabilities and variations are drastic.

I have the following doubts, is it because of

- Small Training/Testing Data set (~ 400 images, I even use Data Augmentation)
- Input Image Shape (even tried with 500x500, started giving me biased results, Or is there any fixed image size like 224x224 in VGG16 for better performance)
- Very less data set in some categories compared to others
- Do I need to add more Convolution & Pooling Layers
- I also tried ADAM and SGD optimizers, results where almost the same
- Does Sequential Model initialize Random weights **model.get_weights()** every time i train the model? Tried a fix for this using **numpy.random.seed(1337)**, fluctuation got fixed for some images.
- Also, when tries different approaches, at times loss gets shooted, while accuracy was still ~80%.

I am getting prediction results like this,

1. [["TypeA", 0.9999998807907104], ["TypeB", 6.756409476338376e-08], ["TypeC", 6.077736847693585e-18]]
2. [["TypeC", 1.0], ["TypeB", 9.148046586956293e-35], ["TypeA", 0.0]]
3. [["TypeB", 1.0], ["TypeC", 0.0], ["TypeA", 0.0]]

The model is saved as check pointed files using Tensorflow session bundle exporter, and served using Tensorflow Serving.

Comment: Do you mean the predicted probability differs when you train the model each time?

Comment: No once trained and deployed, the model gives different probability for the same input

Comment: It is weird. What is your prediction code?

Comment: Do you use `model.predict()`? Or something else?

Comment: @ArunVeeramani comments section is not a good place for pasting results - please edit the post and include the prediction examples there (also the actual command, as kitman0804 asks)

Comment: The interesting part is if I use model.predict(), it doesn't fluctuate but if I serve the exported checkpoint file in tensorflow serving it does fluctuate.

Comment: If the issue is specific to serving, I guess important parts of your serving code would be helpful.